# Unit testing on a build server : Release or Debug code?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, continuous-integration

In .NET(C#) is there any advantage/disadvantage to go with debug/release build for unit testing?

Which target configuration do you usually use for unit testing on a build server? Does it matter?

What about code coverage (for this one I'm guessing debug versions are needed).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend running the release code. For a couple of reasons.

1) It is the code that the customers will be using.

2) Some code has special debug conditionals that will produce differences between the debug and release builds.

Answer (score 8):

You must test the code the way it will ultimately run on the client's machine.  In most sane deployment scenarios that will be code compiled in the Release configuration.

Comment: We actually deploy Debug versions of our code so we can see the entire stack trace when an issue occurs.  Of course all of our code is only used internally.

Comment: You are aware that the Release build also produces a full stack trace?  You get line numbers if you copy the .pdb files.

Comment: When you select "optimize code" (which is usually the case in release build) can't method get inlined or move around slightly that would cause the line number reference to be somewhat misleading?

Answer (score 3):

I would use release build when possible, to get everything as close to the final product as possible.

There are small differences between debug mode and release mode that normally only make a difference for performance, but not result. However, if there is some timing problems with the code they may only show in release mode, so you could take the opportunity to possibly catch those.

Answer (score 2):

Despite most people obviously favour to unit test the release code, I wonder whether the debug build might uncover more errors, though. (I might be wrong)

E.g. afaik in VS debug code, uninitialized variables are forced to some awful value instead of being 0 "by accident". Maybe in .NET it does not make a big difference, but for me, doing mainly algorithmic core code in C++, this can be crucial.

I look forward to any enlightening comments ;).

Comment: In managed world we have compile-time checks for uninitialized variables, so the code will not get the honor to be taken into executable in such state :)

Answer (score 2):

Just adding another reason to test in release mode. Some CI services (Appveyor) will fail the build if it comes across a `Debug.WriteLine()` call, even though the test itself is green.

Answer (score 1):

It is easier (for me) to get to the root of an exception when testing debug code.

Answer (score 1):

We are running both, Debug + Release.

We output a separate tests results xml for each build.

Sometimes there are errors in Debug only, and sometimes in Release only, you want to catch them all ASAP.

Good luck!

Comment: Does it matter if the test fails in Debug if it pass in Release considering that you are deploying only Release configuration of your product?

Comment: Good question. I want to know all to identify any possible issue. It’s not mandatory @Sevenate